# Docker *Image* with a GUI

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run an application with a GUI in docker. There are a bunch of explanations online how to do that, but they all seem to use the native OS repos as opposed to an image repo.

For example - Dockerfile

```
FROM centos
RUN yum install firefox
CMD firefox
```

Then build, with:

```
docker build firefox-gui .
```

and run with:

```
docker run -it --net=host --env="DISPLAY" --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" firefox-gui
```

So what if, for whatever reason, I didn't have access to a yum repo with firefox, but I did have access to an *image* of firefox?

I want to start with a Dockerfile that's something like:

```
FROM docker.io
RUN docker run firefox
```

But obviously that doesn't work as written.

I'm pretty new to docker, so if I've made a gross concept error somewhere that's ok too.

**How do you run a docker image that has a GUI, assuming you don't have access to OS repos within your container?**

Comment: It's kind of a loaded question and depends on what you're trying to do. If you're trying to run a "headless" browser, you need the driver for that browser. In the case of Firefox, that's geckodriver. If you're trying to do browser automation, it might be worth your time to look at the `Dockerfile` in the description of this Docker image. It's a Python + Selenium image used for browser automation that I used a while ago: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/micahparks/seleniumpython

Comment: IMO, this is not a good idea. There are serval blog posts on this topic though, you can easily google this and follow some guide.

Comment: You're trying to run a container from inside of the build of an image? I don't follow the question, but this might be an XY problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the distinction between the two cases you're drawing here.  If you had an image with, say, Firefox, you could `docker run` it the same way you would an image you built yourself.  If you needed to customize it further you could use that image as the `FROM` line in a Dockerfile.

Comment: @DavidMaze - when I "docker run [image-with-gui]" I get some terminal output, indicating that it's running, but I don't actually see the gui. When I google the problem, I get a bunch of walk-throughs like the firefox example telling me to yum install the gui app. I'm probably asking the wrong question on google.

Comment: @BMitch - I am confident that X is part of the issue / solution. I don't actually want to recursively run containers, I want to run image with a gui, and all the googling I've done so far seems to assume that the app is yum-able.